# Debugging OSX app on multiple OSX versions

Tags: xcode, macos

I am not experienced with mac and finding it difficult to find a consistent way of debugging my osx app on different versions for 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9.

I use 10.7 as main machine, with xcode 4.3 can not install xcode 4.3 on 10.9 because it needs newer version of xcode. But latest xcode does not install on 10.7. :/ 
So xcode is coupled with OSX version, if I have to debug on 10.7 , 8 and 9 how do I do it neatly

How you experienced guys handle it ? do you convert projects when switching environment ?

Comment: Are you debugging a specific problem?  If not I would say it's good enough to develop/debug on your main system and then just run/test the app on other versions of OSX.  If you get a crash on one specific OSX version then you can investigate via the crash log and use symbolication to find where in the source the issue occurred.

Comment: Currently I develop the app in the latest version of Xcode and I test it (built in Debug mode) in the older OS Versions. I usually launch it in the command line, so I can see the logs. The problems I usually found are: i) I forgot to check the minimum version for an API, 2) I use a `weak` property for an object which in older OS does not support it. Nevertheless I am also looking to see if there are better ways.